# Cant get assembly binding to work in a Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, azure

I need the following binding:

My setup is as follows.

A website project.
A Cloud Service Webrole that reference the website.
A class library that get called from the webrole startup method and starting a Owin selfhosted service.

```
    var endpoint = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["CompositeServiceEndpoint"];
    string baseUri = string.Format("{0}://{1}",
        endpoint.Protocol, endpoint.IPEndpoint);
    Trace.TraceInformation(String.Format("Starting OWIN at {0}", baseUri));
    _app = WebApp.Start(new StartOptions(url: baseUri), (appbuilder) => new Startup().Configuration(appbuilder, CompositeWebRole.DependencyResolver));
```

This is what fails, it tries to load the 4.0.

```
Plugin Initialization 'Composite.WindowsAzure.Management.Plugins.CompositeManagementPlugin': System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

I have tried adding the assembly binding in the app.config and web.config of the website project. Is this not where I am supposed to put the file?

### update

I have verified that, logging into remote desktop, that f:/approot/ has web.config with the binding inside.

The full error is:

```
Plugin Initialization 'Composite.WindowsAzure.Management.Plugins.CompositeManagementPlugin': System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Composite.WindowsAzure.Management.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app, IWebroleDependencyResolver dpr)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.ResolveApp(StartContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
   at Composite.WindowsAzure.Management.Plugins.CompositeManagementPlugin.InitializePlugin()
   at Composite.WindowsAzure.WebRole.Websites.WebsiteManager.InitializeManager()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
; TraceSource 'WaIISHost.exe' event
```

When i run it in the emulator there is no problems.

Comment: try putting it in a bin directory.

Comment: you might have to deploy web api with your application too.

Comment: the dlls (5.0.0.0) are in the bin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution to the real problem.

I ended up taking the code from Unity WebAPI boostrapper as this was the dependency that pulled in some 4.0.0.0 references to webapi. Kicking out that and just having the implementation in my own dll and not using unity web api bootsrapper solved my problem.

```
// Generated by .NET Reflector from C:\dev\c1\Source\WindowsAzure\packages\Unity.AspNet.WebApi.3.0.1304.0\lib\Net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.WebApi.dll
namespace Microsoft.Practices.Unity.WebApi
{
    using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web.Http.Dependencies;

    public sealed class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver, IDependencyScope, IDisposable
    {
        private IUnityContainer container;
        private SharedDependencyScope sharedScope;

        public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }
            this.container = container;
            this.sharedScope = new SharedDependencyScope(container);
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            return this.sharedScope;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.container.Dispose();
            this.sharedScope.Dispose();
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return this.container.Resolve(serviceType, new ResolverOverride[0]);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return this.container.ResolveAll(serviceType, new ResolverOverride[0]);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private sealed class SharedDependencyScope : IDependencyScope, IDisposable
        {
            private IUnityContainer container;

            public SharedDependencyScope(IUnityContainer container)
            {
                this.container = container;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
            }

            public object GetService(Type serviceType)
            {
                return this.container.Resolve(serviceType, new ResolverOverride[0]);
            }

            public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
            {
                return this.container.ResolveAll(serviceType, new ResolverOverride[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what SDK you are using, I had this problem for days using Azure SDK 2.3.

Since now uses Full IIS, the WebRole cannot see your regular Web.config file or app.config file.
Visual Studio is supposed to do this automatically placing the file in the bin folder, but for some reasons this did not work for me. 
If this is the case do this:

Create a new .config file, name it

```
"yourprojectname".dll.config
```

place into the root of the project and insert the assembly binding code for all the references you need, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <runtime>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
       </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Then deploy the project and the Role will see the new config file.
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Good info - should we make this .config file in our Cloud Project or in the Role Project?